# Who's won more games? X(user) or O(computer) in Tic Tac Toe using Javascript

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

I am week 2 in learning Javascript building a game of Tic Tac Toe and want to record how many wins X or O has had - this is a basic question but I need to get used to the logic I declared two global variables var xWins = 0 & var xWins = 0 ..can't get it to work however

```
function displayWin(player) {
gameover = true;

if player == "X" {
    xWins++;
}
else {
    oWins++;
}
document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = player + " wins!<br><br> " + "-Plays to Date-<br>  X Wins: " + xWins + "<br> O wins: " + oWins;

// ADDED display layover
popup.style.display = "block"; 
olay.style.display = "block"; 
msg.style.display = "none"; 
}
```

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: @Hamms how to record who's won more games X or O?

Comment: Add two global counters: xWinCount and oWinCount. Set both to zero. Then, in your function above, add to the counts depending on who wins, ie. If player = x then xWinCount++

Comment: @TheJonasPersson Thanks mate - tried that logic and updated my code above. Still won't run however...

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to declare global variables outside of the function

```
var xWins = 0;
var oWins = 0;
```

You could add a parameter to `displayWin()` called player, which is a string that is either "X" or "O".

```
function displayWin(player) {
    if player == "X" {
        xWins++;
    }
    else {
        oWins++;
    }
```

There are many approaches to this problem, however, I believe.

Comment: thanks for this! Updated my code in the edit above...did the global variables still won't run however. Snag somewhere...not sure where though...

Comment: Can I see the code where you are calling `displayWin(player)`?

Comment: problem solved mate! Thanks a lot though - yours put me on the right path!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to declare both the `player` and `computer` variables as [Objects](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)

```
var player   = { name: "John", wins: 0 };
var computer = { name: "Computer", wins: 0 };
```

Then, in the function, increment the `wins` attribute of the player (or the computer):

```
function displayWin() {
    gameover = true;
    player.wins++;
}
```